# Spotify api retrieved access token is not working

Tags: c#, webclient, spotify

I am creating a React/C# application with the spotify API, I am receiving an access token but it doesn't work. I get an error (shown below) when trying to make a call to the API (don't know why is says "Invalid username" since it is never used):

> Error: message: "Invalid username" status: 404

`code` is from a earlier step in the authentication process (worked when I used node so I guess that part is correct) and I used all scopes just to be sure that was not a issue `playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-read-recently-played`

My C# code to retrieve the access token:

```
var spotifyClientId = "id";
var spotifySecret = "secret";

var webClient = new WebClient();

var postparams = new NameValueCollection();
postparams.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
postparams.Add("code", code);
postparams.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8000/");

//api documentation says you can post clientid/secret in either body or header
postparams.Add("client_id", spotifyClientId);
postparams.Add("client_secret", spotifySecret);

//var authHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{spotifyClientId}:{spotifySecret}"));
//webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + authHeader);

var tokenResponse = webClient.UploadValues("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", postparams);

var textResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tokenResponse);

return Json(textResponse);
```

So I receive this is the response (note access token is very short)

```
"\"access_token\":\"BQAOYJZnfS0LPEwwZ_06Be76mx59bpoPsVPD0uTvvrwvDtSNi9flgeZQK8kDPSRyTFdE70iBk5PtEAvqnIQ\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"scope\":\"\"}"`
```

And when I try to call the API with this token, I get the error shown above.

If I manually get the token, I can make API calls from frontend

[Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)

Comment: Error 404 is a general access error.  If you have working code best way of getting answer is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the headers in the request of working and non working applications.  Add missing header to non-working application so non-working looks like working app.

Comment: @jdweng I dont see anything weird. I guess i am making some mistake in the C# code retrieving the token but i dont get any error

Comment: The error is due to a missing header or wrong value and will not look weird.  You have to closely look at the headers and find any small differences.  The error is not in the response, it is in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out postman has a code sample after calling authorizations..
After successful oauth verification go to code in right corner and code the code sample, install restsharp and remove some of the parameters so you end up with something like this.

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ODAzNTkzMDMxNzIwNGViNzlhMf54f45f5454fNTJhMTg=");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        request.AddParameter("code", code);
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8000/");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        return Json(response.Content);
```

Comment: you shouldn't need the `request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic...");` line on this call. It exchanges the initial code (after the user logs in on Spotify) for an AccessToken and RefreshToken. Going forward you can use the RefreshToken with the `grant_type` set to `refresh_token` to get new AccessTokens as and when you need them (i.e. when you get a 401 from the API)